# Firebase Firestore queries from array Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way in Firestore to query from an array? The query is built into an three array inside an object.

```
firestore.collection("").where(query.feild[0],query.op[0],query.val[0]).where(query.feild[1],query.op[1],query.val[1])
```

The issue comes when there's more or less items in the array (this is determined by the user). Even if there's no support of this in Firebase what Javascript hack could be done to address the problem other that

```
if(query.val.length === x){query.feild[0 to x]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
var o = firestore.collection("");
for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(query.feild.length, query.op.length, query.val.length); i++){
   o = o.where(query.field[i], query.op[i], query.val[i]);
}
```

You can lose the `Math.min...` part if you're sure that all arrays have the same length;